# Changing the default iTunes download directory

Tags: macos, itunes

Is it possible to change the download directory of iTunes on mac?

- I use mac OSX (10.8.5) and iTunes 11.0.5.
- I want to relocate the directory on a external hard disk storage?

Comment: [iTunes for Mac: Moving your iTunes Media folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449). You may also want to consider [TuneSpan](http://tunespan.com) if you want to automate the process/and or partially move the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the Downloads folder in your `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Downloads` directory to your external drive, and then create a symlink (symbolic link) to the new Downloads location, and place that symlink in the 
`~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Downloads` directory.

Here it is in step form:

1. Quit iTunes.
2. Go to `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media`, and move Downloads to your external drive. Ensure you move the folder, and you don't just make a copy.
3. Open Terminal (located in `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`)
4. Enter `ln -s "/Volumes/NAME_OF_YOUR_EXTERNAL_DRIVE/Downloads" ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads`

Substitute the `NAME_OF_YOUR_EXTERNAL_DRIVE` part with the name of your external drive that you placed Downloads on. Downloads needs to be in the root directory for that command to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The default folder would be

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Downloads
```

You can change the location of your `iTunes Media` folder in `iTunes > Preferences > Advanced`.
But this would mean that you also relocate your Music, Podcasts, Movies and Mobile Apps to the external drive.